# .DWG to ArcMap displays nothing

Tags: arcmap

I have a .DWG (CAD dataset file) that when I bring into ArcMap 10.1, it will not display anything. I've tried converting to a shapefile and importing to geodatabase and I am not able to progress from there. Am I doing something wrong in particular?

Comment: What version is the AutoCAD DWG? Do you have AutoCAD to check the file has content?

Comment: I personally do not have an active licence, but our CAD tech suggested saving it in a different version (2010?). I read this may not help still. I am waiting for the file to be resent to me.

Comment: Knowing what's in the dwg would help. Certain AutoCAD features (like hatches) don't always import well. Additionally you will only see the features and layers turned on in the dwg. If all layers are frozen you won't see anything when you import into ArcMap.

Comment: Well, I was wrong. It is able to display in Arcmap as a saved  2010 version. Now the georeferencing begins.